# Must an inner class use 'this' keyword in order to use outer class method or attributes?

Tags: java, inner-classes, outer-classes

I'm reading the source code of [ArrayList](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) and this class has an inner class with the name `SubList`. I'm looking in a method of the inner class (`SubList`) and see the following methods:

```
 public E set(int index, E e) {
        rangeCheck(index);
        checkForComodification();
        E oldValue = ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);
        ArrayList.this.elementData[offset + index] = e;
        return oldValue;
    }
```

What I see that line 3 & 4 uses `this` keyword in order to call/use `ArrayList` (outer class) method/attribute.
I want to understand is it must to use `OuterClass.this` or `elementData()` will be enough? I run an example long ago (more than a year) and I was able to call an outer class method from an inner class without using `this` keyword.

Comment: It doesn't have to use `ArrayList.this`, but at least to me, that's more readable.

Comment: For members that are in both the inner and outer class, you have to qualify with `Outer.this` if you want the outer member.  This happens most frequently with methods like `Object::equals`, and also frequently happens in various decorator/proxy/combinator situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a *Shadowing* problem that can lead to unexpected behavior and runtime errors.

If a declaration of a type (such as a member variable or a parameter name or method name) in a particular scope (such as an inner class or a method definition) has the same name as another declaration in the enclosing scope, then the declaration shadows the declaration of the enclosing scope. You cannot refer to a shadowed declaration by its name alone.

```java
public class ShadowTest {

    public int x = 0;

    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
        ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x = 23
this.x = 1
ShadowTest.this.x = 0
```

As you can see, to get the correct value of higher scope, you need to use only `ShadowTest.this`.

Thru time your code will mutate and you can miss the same name in the other scope, so you must use only `OuterClass.this` to access outer class scope, make code clear and bulletproof.

See [the Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).